# Code signing error while running on physical device

Tags: iphone, xcode, flutter

So I have an issue while running Flutter app on real device. When I build and run it for simulator - it works fine. But for my iPhone, I have this error message:

```
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Building a deployable iOS app requires a selected Development Team with a 
Provisioning Profile. Please ensure that a Development Team is selected by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities > Team. 
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again

For more information, please visit:
  https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

So I have deleted the `build` folder, also did run `flutter clean` - no result. Opened Xcode, changed iOS deployment target to `9.0`, selected development team account in `Signing & Capabilities` - no result. But what's funny, when I run this project from Xcode on simulator and real device - it works perfectly. Any suggestions on what else can I do? I'm not really sure whether that might be a hint in solving this but I have upgraded to Flutter `3.0.1` few days ago so maybe that's something after upgrading?

Thanks

Comment: Have you apple developer account?

Comment: Yes I do, hence the problem

Comment: This did not happen before the Flutter upgrade

Comment: Before upgrade flutter, you were able to run app in apple real device from xcode?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: delete 

- .symlinks
- Pods
- Podflie
- Podfile.lock

Clear xcode cache from storage

After that 
Try flutter clean

run again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245034/discussion-between-pradip-d-and-mcgtrt).

Answer (score 0):

1 - delete file from ios

- .symlinks
- Pods
- Podflie
- Podfile.lock

Clear xcode cache from storage

After that

```
flutter clean
```

run again!

Happy codding!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working as well. Still thinking that might be only a problem related to a flutter version change. But still it's confusing why it's does not work

Comment: For run app in real device you must have an apple developer account! without it you can never run app in real device.